# How does Dimensional Anchor work on a permanent dimensional gateway?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, portals

Does [Dimensional Anchor](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Dimensional%20Anchor) work if cast on a permanent dimensional gateway of conjuration (summoning)? Or can it blocks the passage of summoned creatures?
From the rules the description of dimensional anchor is:

> *A green ray springs from your hand. You must make a ranged touch attack to hit the target. Any creature or object struck by the ray is covered with a shimmering emerald field that completely blocks extradimensional travel.*

Comment: What effect creates (or is) a permanent dimensional gateway of the summoning subschool?

Comment: I answer for my GM: Actually I had in mind a physical portal like the Mirror of Mental Prowess. To me, Dimensional Anchor is intended to be cast upon the item or creature who is teleported, not upon the means by which they are teleported. But this is not clearly specified in the text. Taken litterally it could work if casted on a Mirror of Mental Prowess, although to me the spell wasn't designed to be used this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It would block the portal only if it also is a creature or object

The spell says:

> Any **creature or object** struck by the ray is covered with a shimmering emerald field that completely blocks extradimensional travel.

So if this works will depend on the nature of the portal. The portal needs to also be a creature or object, otherwise you cannot target it with the spell. A creature is defined under [common terms](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Common%20Terms&Category=Basics) as "A creature is an active participant in the story or world. This includes PCs, NPCs, and monsters."
Object is [not a defined term](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139928/where-can-i-find-the-definition-of-object), so there is some leeway in GM ruling here.

For example, a [Portal Oak](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicPlantsDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Portal%20Oak) could be considered an object or a creature, and be targeted by the spell, blocking its function, or a [Mirror of Mental Prowess](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Mirror%20of%20Mental%20Prowess) as a magic item would be an object that could likewise be blocked from functioning as a portal.

On the other hand, a portal such as a [gate](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Gate) has no actual physical substance, so even if made permanent, it will not count as an object and cannot be targeted by the spell.

The more common appliction would be to cast this spell *on the creature or object you want to keep from traveling*, so they cannot use another, independent portal or spell to do so, but the way it is written would seem to allow to also block a portal from being passable, if you can target it, because that also could be

> covered with a shimmering emerald field that completely blocks extradimensional travel

---

P.S. Your question asks specifically about spells from the Conjuration (Summoning) school that create a permanent dimensional gateway. There are very few such spells. The only one I found is [Elemental Swarm](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Elemental%20Swarm) and it only has a duration of 10 minutes per level. The portal created there is of the non-object nature that you could not cast Dimensional Anchor on. I suspect you mean just a portal or dimensional gateway in general, that could be used to conjure or summon monsters.